# Yii cgridview cactivedataprovider doesnt work properly

Tags: yii, yii-components, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I configured the Yii cactivedataprovider as the documentation writes:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->together = true;

$criteria->with = array(
        'relationId0',
        'relationId1',
        ... 
);

$criteria->compare('"relationId0".property0', $this->relationId0_property0, true);
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'sort' => array(
            'attributes' => array(
                ...
                'relationId0.property0' => array(
                    'asc' => '"relationId0".property0',
                    'desc' => '"relationId0".property0 DESC',
                ),
                ...
             )
         )
));
```

so, when the ->together is false, then the gridview works properly and gets all rows what the pagination allowed, but in this case the compare (so the search) doesnt work (because this way doesnt use the related objects in the sql query),

but when ->together is true (and it is the solution supposedly) the compare is working but the gridview gets random number of rows in each page.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `pagination` into your dataprovider.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>10),
    'sort' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
            ...
            'relationId0.property0' => array(
                'asc' => '"relationId0".property0',
                'desc' => '"relationId0".property0 DESC',
            ),
            ...
         )
     )
));
```

This should solve your problem.